# SQL Query Not Working, Returning Nothing Back

Tags: sql, postgresql

The goal of my query is to return the country, capital, and number of languages spoken. It also needs to be ordered by descending number of languages spoken, and then by capital. Finally, the number of languages must be at least 5 and 10 or less.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT country.name                    AS Country,
       city.name                       AS Capital,
       Count(countrylanguage.language) AS NumLanguages
FROM   country,
       city,
       countrylanguage
WHERE  city.id = country.capital
GROUP  BY city.name,
          country.name
HAVING ( Count(countrylanguage.language) BETWEEN 5 AND 10 );
```

It returns nothing. The where clause is necessary in order to get the city name to display. In the country table is just an id number, and then the city table holds the id number and name.

If anyone could spot my error I"d be very grateful!

Comment: Is this homework? It's fine if so, just best to mention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the relationship with `countrylanguage`. Without it, you have a cartesian product, so `Count(countrylanguage.language)` is equal the number of records in `countrylanguage`, which is most likely to be greater then 10.

Here's a proposed solution (adjust with field names/DB structure accordingly):

```
SELECT country.name                    AS Country,
       city.name                       AS Capital,
       Count(countrylanguage.language) AS NumLanguages
FROM   country,
       city,
       countrylanguage
WHERE  city.id = country.capital
AND    countrylanguage.language_id = country.language_id
GROUP  BY city.name,
          country.name
HAVING ( Count(countrylanguage.language) BETWEEN 5 AND 10 )
ORDER BY NumLanguages desc, city.Name
```

That said, you should always try to avoid joins in the `WHERE` clause of the query (implicit joins). Favoring explicit (declarative) joins will give you more readability and also more flexibility.

**Update**

As per comments suggestion, here is the query's version using ANSI-92 join syntax:

```
SELECT country.name                    AS Country,
       city.name                       AS Capital,
       Count(countrylanguage.language) AS NumLanguages
FROM       country
INNER JOIN city on city.id = country.capital
INNER JOIN countrylanguage on countrylanguage.language_id = country.language_id
GROUP  BY city.name,
          country.name
HAVING ( Count(countrylanguage.language) BETWEEN 5 AND 10 ); 
ORDER BY NumLanguages desc, city.Name
```

Comment: If that works, I'm impressed. A cartesian product would return too many rows, not none, as the OP said.

Comment: @ahillman3 Read my updated answer. OP wants groups `HAVING ( Count(countrylanguage.language) BETWEEN 5 AND 10 )`, so **many** is most likely more than 10

Comment: @ahillman3 - I agree that this is likely the explanation. No ANSI-92 join syntax though? If the OP used it in the first place they wouldn't have had this issue...

Comment: @Adrian - Very good point. Most likely the cause. The additional info you added helped as well, I looked at it prior to your final edit.

Comment: @MartinSmith I had mentioned that in an edit, now I updated the answer, adding the code

Comment: You could also make use of table aliases to make it easier to read.

Comment: @Adrian I appreciate your quick answer! I have spotted my error based on your code, however it is still not quite behaving as I wanted. I need it to display the results in order of greatest count(countrylangage) then by capital. RIght now I have it as ORDER BY NumCities, Capital DESC but this produces a result where the NumCities are ASC order while the Capital is DESC order. Thoughts?

Comment: @Adrian I need all results of where its 10 to display all together, ordered by ascending capital, then results by 9 all together and ordered by ascending capital, etc